# How to stop using Anaconda's Version of OpenSSL

Tags: command-line, 18.04, openssl, anaconda

I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openssl
```

and the output was:

```
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1).
```

However, when I type `openssl version -a` into the terminal, the output is:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: /tmp/build/80754af9/openssl_1522162531585/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/openssl_1522162531585/work=/usr/local/src/conda/openssl-1.0.2o -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/vedantroy/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -Wa,--noexecstack -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/ssl"
```

Furthermore, typing `which openssl` outputs: `/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/bin/openssl`.

It seems my system is using the conda installation of "openssl" instead of the one installed by `apt-get`. How do I force my system to use the version of "openssl" that is installed by `apt-get`?

Answer (score 4):

The `openssl` package installs an executable file called `openssl` as `/usr/bin/openssl` (see `dpkg -L openssl`).

You have `openssl` installed as `/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/bin/openssl`.

The directory `/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/bin` occurs in `$PATH` before `/usr/bin` appears.

Your `$SHELL` picks the first `openssl` it sees.

You have several choices:

- Rearrange `$PATH`. However, if there are any other system binaries Anaconda wants to override, this will screw that up.
- I assume that you own the directory `/home/vedantroy/anaconda3/bin`, so `chmod -x /home/vedantroy/anaconda3/bin/openssl;rehash` will let you use `/usr/bin/openssl`.
- Add `alias openssl="/usr/bin/openssl"` to your `~/.bashrc`. WIll only work for shells.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I suggest creating an alias to `apt` installed version of `openssl`:

```
alias openssl='/usr/bin/openssl'
```

Put your alias somewhere which it gets sourced automatically like: `.bashrc`.

You can also run it directly:

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Or change the `PATH` environment variable, which can't be a good option in your case because you are actually using Anaconda.

Whenever you want to use Anaconda version then run one of these:

```
\openssl
""openssl
''openssl
'openssl'
"openssl"
command openssl
```

Comment: please explain the characters before the openssl!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Causes aliases to be ignored and the actual comment be invoked or bash built-in if any exists (Which in this case there is no built-in  so the actual command will get to run).

Answer (score 2):

Conda may be active by default in your shell, often the case for an anaconda installation on Ubuntu. There may be `(base)` at the beginning of your shell prompt.

Simply running `conda deactivate` may fix the issue. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Given the previous answers I tried the following things to resolve the issue.

1. Adding an `alias` in `.bashrc` didn't work since the conda openssl was picked every time the `.bashrc` file was `sourced`. Still haven't figured out why that happened.
2. Adding `/usr/bin/openssl` before anaconda in `$PATH` environment variable didn't work since it requires to specify the whole `bin` directory in `$PATH` not just the executable `openssl`. Adding `/usr/bin` directory to `$PATH` before `/home/user/anaconda3/bin` creates another issue for me since it causes the `python` version of system installation to take precedence over the anaconda python version something that I'm avoiding due to my setup.

The following solution works if you want to have your default system wide `openssl` being picked up but at the same time using your anaconda python version as your default.

In other words stop using anacondas' `openssl` while still maintaining the following env. variable `export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

The solution (at least for me) involves the use of symbolic links.

```
mv ~/anaconda3/bin/openssl ~/anaconda3/bin/orig_openssl # rename anaconda openssl
ln -s /usr/bin/openssl /home/user/anaconda3/bin/openssl # link openssl from OS to anaconda bin dir.
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear as to did the link fix it.